# Не хватает перевода про авторизацию для зимних шляп

Tags: дефект, локализация, новогодние-шляпы

Например, по [этой ссылке](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/rep-hunter) я вижу такое:

> [image]

P.s. правда, может быть это вовсе не локализуемо, как и ссылки в шапке.

Comment: И традусёр лежит.

Comment: @Suvitruf разве? У меня фурычит.

Comment: У меня не работает =/